# How can I fetch complicated structure data from Firebase Realtime database in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the Firebase database:

[image: Firebase Image]

```
const [seriesList, setSeriesList] = useState([]);
function getSeriesList() {
    database()
    .ref('/Categories/Series/')
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      var main = [];
            main.push({
                season: child.value.seaason,
                **// Here how can I know that how many seasons or episodes are there**
          });
        });
        setSeriesList(sortArrayAsc(main));
    });
}
```

I want to display data like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Should I change anything in the database structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is there a problem with the code in the question? Is something not working? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a for loop for getting the list of "Season", then you'll get the key as well as value to push in array, It'll be like this:

```
const [seriesList, setSeriesList] = useState([]);
function getSeriesList() {
    database()
    .ref('/Series/Dark/Season/')
    .on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
      var main = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          main.push({
            link: child.val().link,
            title: child.val().title,
          });
        });
      });
    setSeriesList(sortArrayAsc(main));
    });
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for Answering. But i need to know that how can I get the number Seasons And Episodes to display on screen. (As show in a screenshot).

Comment: Try, “child.key”!